# How do I use a method that takes a string as an argument, and turn it into a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

How do I use a method that takes a string as an argument, and turn it into a hash that show the keys: as the words and the values: as the number of times the words occur in the string?

```
def my_string(string)

end

my_string("This is my string, or could be any string.")
```

I was thinking that I would have to `string.split(" ")` and somehow use an array.

```
def my_string(string)
  string.split(" ")

  string_hash = {}

  string.each_with_index do |element, index|
    string_hash[index] = element
  end
end

my_string("This is my string, or could be any string.")
```

Comment: And where's the code that you wrote for this? What was the output of your code? What wasn't working exactly??

Comment: So far I haven't really gotten very far. I was trying to see anyone new if there was a way to do this.

Comment: Another way to do this `string.split.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)`

Comment: this solution works only if transform_values exist which is only for ruby 2.4+. Also, it won't exclude the special characters if there is any as it is in yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
def my_string(str)
  str.downcase.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
end

str = "A cat, a dog and another cat."
my_string str
  #=> {"a"=>2, "cat"=>2, "dog"=>1, "and"=>1, "another"=>1}
```

This uses the form of the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument that is a default value. That simply means that if a hash `h = Hash.new(d)` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, `d`, which here is `0`. (The hash is not changed.)

The steps are as follows.

```
s = str.downcase
  #=> "a cat, a dog and another cat."
a = s.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/)
  #=> ["a", "cat", "a", "dog", "and", "another", "cat"]
e = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "cat", "a", "dog", "and", "another", "cat"]:
  #     each_with_object({})>
```

The first value is generated by the enumerator and passed to the block, and the block variables `s` and `h` are assigned values.

```
s,h = e.next
  #=> ["a", {}]
s #=> "a"
h #=> {}
h[s] += 1
  # h["a"] = h["a"] + 1 => h["a"] = 0 + 1 => h["a"] = 1
```

When Ruby sees `h["a"] += 1` (when parsing), the first thing she does is expand that to `h["a"] = h["a"] + 1`. Since `h` is initially empty (and therefore has no key `"a"`), `h["a"]` on the right side of the equality returns the default value of `0`. Continuing,

```
s,h = e.next
  #=> ["cat", {"a"=>1}]
s #=> "cat"
h #=> {"a"=>1}
h[s] += 1
  # h["cat"] = h["cat"] + 1 => h["cat"] = 0 + 1 => h["cat"] = 1

s,h = e.next
  #=> ["a", {"a"=>1, "cat"=>1}]
s #=> "a"
h #=> {"a"=>1, "cat"=>1}
h[s] += 1
  # h["a"] = h["a"] + 1 => h["a"] = 1 + 1 => h["a"] = 2
h #=> {"a"=>2, "cat"=>1}
```

This time `h` has a key `"a"`, so `h["a"]` on the right side of the equality returns the value for that key, `1`.

The remaining steps are similar.

Comment: Finally, a regex suitable for 21st century :)

Comment: `Enumerable#count_by` really is a missing piece. :(

Comment: Why `split` and not `scan`, though? The latter seems to be more suitable, intent-wise.

Comment: @Sergio, yes on `scan` (edited). You should propose `Enumerable#count_by` be added to the Ruby core.

Comment: They'll want some code, I'm afraid, and I am not that well-versed in C. :/